# how to set isConnected value false by default in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have created a nointernet connection check screen. and now I want to test for No internet connection. so How could I set isConnected Value False.

here is my code

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { View, Text, Button, Alert, Platform, alert } from "react-native";
import {useNetInfo} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export const NoConnection = ({navigation}) => {
  const netInfo = useNetInfo();

  if (netInfo.isConnected) {
    navigation.navigate("Login")
  }
  return (
    <View>
       <Text>Type: {netInfo.type}</Text>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use useState hook, set default to true , then if connected  update state to false.

```
import React, { Component,useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, Alert, Platform, alert } from "react-native";
import NetInfo,{useNetInfo}  from "@react-native-community/netinfo"
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export const NoConnection = ({navigation}) => {

const netInfo = useNetInfo();

//declare a isConnected hook with default true
const [isConnected, setConnectedState] = useState(true)
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
            setConnectedState(state.isConnected)
 });

if(isConnected === false) {

    console.log("Is connected is", isConnected)
} else {
    console.log("Is connected is", isConnected)
}

}


  return (
    <View>
       <Text>Type: {netInfo.type}</Text>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

you can further learn about hooks and state from the below link.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

Comment: I am not getting please. please write whole code with state also

Comment: I have edit kindly check, if working for you.

Comment: No its saying undefined is not an object (evaluating)'netinfo.Netingo.fetch')

Comment: have you imported NetInfo via import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227513/discussion-between-sohil-shaikh-and-shahid-nawaz).